# Noise (in dB) added to a signal but within range limits

Tags: python, noise, digital-to-analog

I have a sine wave signal to which I add noise in terms of dB.
This is based on
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058340/adding-noise-to-a-signal-in-python

The signal is sent to a DAC and there lays my issue, when adding noise to the signal, which may lay between -1 and 1, the noise could cause the signal to lay between -(1 + x) and (1 + x) where x is noise.

The DAC can take a signal only between values A and B, how can I send the maximal possible amplitude signal to the DAC without exceeding A or B? My assumption was clamping to A and B when exceeded but a block-wave-like output is resulting.

Could I do something to still have the noise level in dB but not exceed A and B, whilst using the full range between A and B?

The signal is created in Python first, later added as a look-up-table to the transmitter.

My code: (based on answer in the link provided above)

```
sig_watts = [x**2 for x in signal]
sig_avg_watts = np.mean(sig_watts)
sig_avg_db = 10 * np.log10(sig_avg_watts)
# Calculate noise according to [2] then convert to watts
noise_avg_db = sig_avg_db - SNR
noise_avg_watts = 10 ** (noise_avg_db / 10)
# Generate an sample of white noise
mean_noise = 0
noise_volts = np.random.normal(mean_noise, np.sqrt(noise_avg_watts), len(sig_watts))
# Noise up the original signal
signal = signal + noise_volts 
# clamp
for i in range(len(signal)):
    if signal[i] > B:
        signal[i] = B
    elif signal[i] < A:
        signal[i] = A
```

I have a suggestion:
if my signal would be greater than B, could I say:

```
if signal[i] > B : signal[i] = B - (signal[i] - B)
```

In that sense I would subtract the exceeding part from B, or would that influence my noise level?

Comment: Clamping is a bad idea, as it distorts the signal. Better is to scale the entire signal: find `k` such that `k*signal` is within bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's typically best to leave 1 dB or so of headroom between the peak of your signal and the output capabilities of the DAC. One of the more subtle points is that the max of the digital samples does NOT necessarily equal the peak of the analog waveform, so there is some risk of clipping something downstream even you digital data is not clipped.

1 dB of headroom means you should scale your full scale data by 0.89125 before sending to to the DAC.

The headroom for moderate to high SNR, the headroom can typically absorb a little extra noise. For example let's assume an SNR of 35dB where the signal is sine wave with an amplitude of one. The sine wave power is -3dB(DFS) so the noise power would be -38dB(DFS). Technically speaking Gaussian noise as a no well defined peak amplitude, however in practice assumption of $x_{max} = 5$ for a noise power of 1 works quite well (for various reasons).

Running the math, we can a maximum amplitude of about 0.95 (after the output scaling of -1dB), which is still comfortably below the clipping point.

If you have lower SNR or more noise, you may have to increase your headroom. The main impact of increasing headroom is more quantization noise, but this shouldn't matter for you since you are probably adding noise at a much higher level anyway. Obviously you use a little bit of output gain but in most cases that can easily be adjusted after the DAC in the analog domain.